# How do I join these two together? Varchar guid and guid type both primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to compare two different column types (not my doing, part of a data conversion project). One has form guids stored similar to the following:

```
0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5
```

The other has them stored as the following:

```
{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5}
```

What would be the best way to join both of these tables on this column (unfortunately it's a primary key for both). So far I've tried casting one table as a guid (with no success) and also tried to build a like statement - but have been unsure how to approach this.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

In case it's the data, is this syntactically correct?

```
inner join  report_temp.workflow_lease_proposal lp
    on wif.form_guid like '%' + lp.form_guid + '%'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server is quit intelligent when it comes to comparing values having different datatypes.

Following script works as is without any explicit conversion

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (VARCHARID VARCHAR(48) PRIMARY KEY)
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (GUIDID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES 
    ('{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5}')
  , ('{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B6}')
  , ( '0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B7' )
  , ( '0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B8' )

INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES 
    ('{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5}')
  , ( '0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B6' )
  , ('{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B7}')
  , ( '0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B8' )

SELECT  *
FROM    @TableA a
        INNER JOIN @TableB b ON b.GUIDID = a.VARCHARID
```

**Result**

```
VARCHARID                               GUIDID
{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5}  0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B5
{0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B6}  0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B6
0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B7    0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B7
0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B8    0CAF3FBC-3C76-420B-B0C4-42867551E3B8
```

Comment: You are a god amongst men. Thank-you for the detailed answer. Looks like it's my data then (damn!).

Answer (score 4):

```
inner join  report_temp.workflow_lease_proposal lp
    on 
cast(wif.form_guid as varchar(36))  = cast(lp.form_guid as varchar(36))
```