# SQL error when casting guid to string

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working with SSIS packages, and I use OLE DB Source component with following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @ConnectedGUIDS nvarchar(200);

SELECT @ConnectedGUIDS = COALESCE(@ConnectedGUIDS + ',', '') + convert(nvarchar(36), Record2Id)
FROM ConnectionBase 
WHERE Record1Id = CAST(? AS CHAR(36));

SELECT DISTINCT(Record1Id) AS ContractGUID,  
       @ConnectedGUIDS AS ConnectedGUIDs 
FROM ConnectionBase 
WHERE Record1Id = CAST(? AS CHAR(36));
```

When I try running package, it fails in pre-execute phase, with following error:

> Error: 0xC0202009 at Update connected contracts in Stage DB, Get
>   connected Contracts from CRM DB [5]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.". Error: 0xC004701A at
>   Update connected contracts in Stage DB, SSIS.Pipeline: Get connected
>   Contracts from CRM DB failed the pre-execute phase and returned error
>   code 0x80040E14.

These are the types I have:

- `?` is parameter mapped in loop container and it is String representation of GUID
- `Record1Id` is `uniqueidentifier`
- `Record2Id` is `uniqueidentifier`

If I replace

```
CAST(? AS CHAR(36))
```

with

```
CAST('9C5D6FA0-4EBD-41F6-9D31-FB62A885CEC6' AS CHAR(36))
```

I can run same query in SQL Server Management Studio without any problems.
I have same exact query in another SSIS package and its not causing any problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, for one thing your error is stating it is occurring when the conversion is `FROM STRING TO UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.`

Comment: As @clifton_h has stated, the problem is in your SQL not your SSIS. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288732/how-do-i-join-these-two-together-varchar-guid-and-guid-type-both-primary-keys